# Target `label` tag next to `input` using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to target the label using `.closest('label')`, `.next('label')` to target the `label`. What am I missing?

```js
$('input').on('focus', function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass('textblock');
  $(this).next('label').css('top', '-27px');
  console.log('hello');
});

$('input').on('blur', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == '')
    $(this).parent().removeClass('textblock');
  $(this).next('label').css('top', '11px');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <input type="text" class="form-control not-required" name="portfolio_link" value="">
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <label for="portfolio_link" class="input-empty">Portfolio Link</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`next()` will target next sibling, so

You can use:

```
$(this).parent().find('label');
```

Also, you can target directly:

```
$('.input-empty').css('top', '-27px');
```

```js
$('input').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('textblock');
    $(this).parent().find('label').css('top', '-27px');
    console.log('hello');
});

$('input').on('blur', function() {
    if($(this).val() == '')
        $(this).parent().removeClass('textblock');
        $(this).parent().find('label').css('top', '11px');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control not-required" name="portfolio_link" value="">
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label for="portfolio_link" class="input-empty">Portfolio Link</label>
</div>
```

Comment: As a rule, I _strongly_ avoid the use of `.parent`, in favor of `.closest`.  Much more tolerant to DOM changes....

Answer (score 0):

`next()` won't work because it targets the immediately following sibling, but the immediately following sibling of the `input` in your example is the `span`. You can use `siblings()` instead:

```js
$('input').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('textblock');
    $(this).siblings('label').css('top', '-27px');
    console.log('hello');
});

$('input').on('blur', function() {
    if($(this).val() == '')
        $(this).parent().removeClass('textblock');
        $(this).siblings('label').css('top', '11px');
});
```

```css
.form-group {
  margin-top:30px;
}
label {
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control not-required" name="portfolio_link" value="">
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label for="portfolio_link" class="input-empty">Portfolio Link</label>
</div>
```

Comment: @cale_b My answer suggests using `siblings()`, not `parent()`. Even using `closest()`, the javascript may break if the DOM structure changes(i.e. moving the label outside of the div containing the input).

Comment: Hey, my sincere apologies.  I thought I was posting this comment against the _question_, not your answer.  Your answer is excellent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to always target the respective `label` for an `input`, you can query it via the `name` attribute of the affected `input` element:

```js
$('input').on('focus', function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass('textblock');
  $('label[for="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]').css('top', '-27px');
  console.log('hello');
});

$('input').on('blur', function() {
  if ($(this).val() === '')
    $(this).parent().removeClass('textblock');
  $('label[for="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]').css('top', '11px');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <input type="text" class="form-control not-required" name="portfolio_link" value="">
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <label for="portfolio_link" class="input-empty">Portfolio Link</label>
</div>
```